# Show div depending on a search

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a small problem with a script that I want to find and show different divs depending on a search. The original script is something I found and used for a contact list, and that I now want to configure to do something else.
[Original code (JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/WBvTj/4/)

My edited code:

```js
$('.Fruit').hide();
$('#search').click(function() {
  $('.Fruit').hide();
  var txt = $('#search-criteria').val();
  $('.Fruit').each(function() {
    if ($(this).id.toUpperCase().indexOf(txt.toUpperCase()) != -1) {
      $(this).show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search-criteria" />
<input type="button" id="search" value="search" />
<div class="Fruit" id="Apple">
  <h3>Some text about apples</h3>
</div>
<div class="Fruit" id="Orange">
  <h3>Some text about oranges</h3>
</div>
```

I don't know if you understand what I'm trying to achieve...? I have, in this case, two divs - Apple and Orange. By default both are hidden, but if I enter Apple for instance in the search field and push the search button, the div "Apple" will show, and if I instead search for "Orange" then obviously I want the "Orange" div to show. If I search for anything else nothing will show, as long as there's not a div with an id that matches the searchword.

So basically I'm trying to build a database of preloaded content that can be searched and shown on the fly without reloading the page.

The error is, as far as I can understand, when I try to address and compare the divs id with the searchword on row 6 in the JS. Does anyone know how to do this, and make this work? Or does anyone have another solution that can perform this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because jQuery objects do not have an `id` property. You need to use `prop('id')` or just `this.id`.

Also note that you can improve your logic by making the `id` attributes you match with lower case, then convert the input to lower case, then you can just use a normal selector, like this:

```js
$('#search').click(function() {
  var txt = $('#search-criteria').val();
  if (txt)
    $('.fruit').hide().filter('#' + txt.toLowerCase()).show();
});
```

```css
.fruit {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search-criteria" />
<input type="button" id="search" value="search" />
<div class="fruit" id="apple">
  <h3>Some text about apples</h3>
</div>
<div class="fruit" id="orange">
  <h3>Some text about oranges</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it!

Comment: But I now noticed that if you enter nothing, that is perform a blank search, both divs show. I'd like a blank search to result in that nothing i s shown, or even better, a message that nothing was found. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Ah yes, you need a condition to check that something was entered. I updated again

Comment: And the with an else show another div with some "not found" message?

Comment: No, you'd need to change the logic for that. If you want that behaviour I'd suggest starting a new question.

Comment: Very thankful for your great help! Is it possible to trouble you with help for the last piece of the puzzle, that is error handling if the searchword is empty or not found?

Comment: Again, that's a separate issue to what was in the question, so you should start a new one for that

Comment: Ok, I'll do that! Again, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: No problem at all. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped