# Error handling in a Javascript search function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

this is actually a follow up question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47377956/show-div-depending-on-a-search)
that was solved thanks to [Rory McCrossan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/519413/rory-mccrossan).
I now have this functioning script; a search function that shows a div depending on a searchword.

**JS**

```
$('#search').click(function() {
  var txt = $('#search-criteria').val();
  if (txt)
    $('.fruit').hide().filter('#' + txt.toLowerCase()).show();
});
```

**CSS**

```
.fruit {
    display: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script
<input type="text" id="search-criteria" />
<input type="button" id="search" value="search" />
<div class="fruit" id="apple">
    <h3>Some text about apples</h3>
</div>
<div class="fruit" id="orange">
    <h3>Some text about oranges</h3>
</div>
```

What I now wonder is if someone could help me with some kind of error handling to add to this script, preferably that can be smoothly added without rewriting the logic of the script. I.e. I'd like to display another div with a message when the search comes up with no result and/or when the user makes an empty string search.

Since I'm actually an UX designer my technical skills are somewhat limited and I'm therefore very grateful if someone could help me with this...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**simple javascipt error handing using try and catch:--**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

function adddlert2($a){
alert($a);
}


try {
    adddlert("Welcome guest!");
}
catch(err) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = err.message;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Another error handing(javascript example) using javascript SEARCH function:--**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
try {

    var str_wrong = "Visit"; 
    var n = str.search("Visit");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
   
}
catch(err) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = err.message;
 }
   
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use try and catch in this case, but If you want to be informed about all irregularities in your application I prefer to use dedicated services for this job.

I use [Sentry.io](https://sentry.io/welcome/), this is nice service to handle exceptions and errors in backend and frontend. Is simple to use, you only need to add one additional JS script without modifying existing code. More about installation process [here](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you're looking for is this :) I know changing to .keyup() had nothing to do with your question, so change it back if you like

```
<input type="text" id="search-criteria" />
<input type="button" id="search" value="search" />
<div id="default" class="fruit">
    no fruit found
</div>
<div class="fruit" id="apple">
  <h3>Some text about apples</h3>
</div>
<div class="fruit" id="orange">
  <h3>Some text about oranges</h3>
</div>
```

and

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#search-criteria').keyup(function() {
            var txt = $('#search-criteria').val();
            if (txt){
                var elements = $('.fruit').hide().filter('#' + txt.toLowerCase());
                if(elements.length > 0){
                    elements.show();
                }
                else{
                    $("#default").html("No result found for "+txt);
                    $("#default").show();
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $("#default").hide();
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```